# Customise Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is there any way to remove all the buttons(including tab close and browser close min max buttons), Bars(title , tab, menu, ect. ) in firefox but with out going to fullscreen. Yet there should be a way to go to previous page and next page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for kiosk mode:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mkiosk/

Comment: thanks for the reply. but kiosk always go to full screen mode and remove ability to go back. if there is something like kikos yet customisable then would be great.

Answer (score 0):

check the link below for more information
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-themes-change-look-of-firefox